# Indeterminate Slider being dismissed

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Currently implementing the last example at

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/slider

but with only one card (loading card)

problem is that if I scroll (swipe forward or backward) the slider gets dismissed

How do I keep the slider from getting dismissed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Slider is a global component that gets overwritten when another client requests it, in this case, the `CardScrollView`.

One way to solve this would be for you to `CardScrollView`'s scroll bar in your `onCreate()` method with:

```
mCardScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: It worked but only part way. After I emptied the scroll view (loading card) and inserted the new cards the slider had to be dismissed programatically and scrollbar needed to be re-enabled